# Interesting pattern in the number of steps in the Collatz conjecture.

Tags: collatz-conjecture

[image]

I was playing around with the Collatz conjecture and plotting random things when I came across this.

The x axis is the natural numbers and the y axis is the number of steps it takes for each number to reach one.

This looked interesting to me, I mean, there is definitely a pattern here, don't you agree? :)

Does this look similar to anything?

Comment: Did you use Mathematica to plot this?

Comment: Yes, I manually generated a bunch of numbers and plotted them using Mathematica.

Comment: 'manually generated a bunch of numbers' - A bunch?

Comment: numbers and the number of steps it took them to reach one up to 50000.

Comment: The x axis has been cut out in the screenshot. It goes up to 50000.

Comment: The picture also appears in this article (https://arxiv.org/abs/1911.01229), so maybe there's also some information in it that you consider interesting.

Comment: the lower chart at https://oeis.org/A006577/graph is similar

Comment: Thanks. I'll check them out. :)

Comment: I've seen this plot before.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/687416/are-there-any-explanations-for-these-patterns-in-the-collatz-sequences

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You asked if your plot looks similar to anything. The simple answer is that the plot is not new as similar ones can be found on [Collatz conjecture Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture).

Your other question ask if anyone agrees that there is a pattern. Yes, I do agree there is a general pattern. The graph shows that at different depths on the Collatz tree with root 1, there are clusters of numbers whose distance apart is small; hence the appearance of dashed lines. Additionally, the curved downward patterns are an indication that some small natural numbers require more steps to reach 1 than the larger natural numbers that they ascend to before the trajectories descend.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it out.:)

Answer (score 0):

There's two ways to answer what it looks like. As for what other "graph" or "spiral" it looks like, what comes to mind is the [Sacks Spiral](https://www.naturalnumbers.org/sparticle.html) which I think has to do with prime numbers.
[Sacks Spiral image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BI64j.png) (The Sacks spiral is not the closest lookalike I admit.)

Your picture also looks like the intersection of a bunch of logarithms (green) and negative logarithms (red). I'm not saying that's what it is, just what it looks like.
[collatz steps image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gzXIa.png)

It also looks to me like there's some kind of 3D thing going on, even though it's a 2D image. This is the same graph as yours, but from 1 to a 100 million, taken from Wikipedia. [Cylindrical shape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zL7Q9.jpg). It looks like a cylinder to me.